# How to calculate latency between two different brain region in Steinmetz dataset?

Tags: vision, brain, motor

I am new to Computational Neuroscience and recently, I came across to Steinmetz dataset and looking into the dataset, I had an idea of calculating the latency between two brain regions in terms of passing information.

Initially, I have this idea to calculate the latency by analysing the time difference between visual stimuli and response time but, it won't give me latency answer for middle regions which come between visual and motor cortex. And it made me more curious.

Btw, I am an AI researcher, with a background in Image processing and Reinforcement learning. Trying to get into Brain Machine Inspired models (BMI). It'll be really helpful, if someone could guide me